# Does quark theory account for the masses and radiuses of the elementary particles?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

Can quark theory account for the masses and radiuses of the proton and other elementary particles? What kind of orbits, if any, do the three quarks in a proton follow? Do the two positively charged quarks orbit the third negatively charged quark in the center, or are the orbits of the three quarks more complex?

Comment: Orbits are classical concepts: they really don't apply to what's happening in a proton (or an atom for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

To some extent. The mass of the quarks is quite low, much less than that of the proton or the neutron. But confinement to a volume of about a femtometer in diameter means that their momentum must be large, according to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. This gives a kinetic energy $E \approx pc$ for each of them of about 300 MeV. In total just about the mass of the proton and the neutron. (This is a bit of a coincidence.)

See Frank Wilczek, "[Mass without mass](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.882879)", Physics Today **52**, 11 (1999).

Comment: the gluons that mediate the strong force also contribute to the hadron masses. @pieter, do you happen to know by how much? I cannot remember at the moment.

Comment: @nielsnielsen It seems that this whole picture is awfully oversimplified, but this is as far as my understanding of QCD goes. Luckily, the experts are making progress: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14381

Comment: There are also good articles on this topic on Frank Wilczek's Web site.

Answer (score 0):

> Can quark theory account for the masses and radiuses of the proton and other elementary particles?

Quark theory, as expressed  in the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) , is a quantum mechanical theory based on [quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory), and has axiomatically the elementary particles with zero radius, i.e. point particles.

The proton *is not* an elementary particle . All [hadrons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/hadron.html) are composed out of quarks and the theory in detail becomes complicated due to the nature of the force between quarks. The interactions in the bag of hadrons is complicated [as seen here](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/).

[image]

> What kind of orbits, if any, do the three quarks in a proton follow? 
>   Do the two positively charged quarks orbit the third negatively charged quark in the center, or are the orbits of the three quarks more complex?

As the graphic shows  nothing can be described even approximately by the classical term "orbit". It is a quantum mechanical system with a large  number of constituents whose sum of quantum numbers adds up to the quantum numbers of the proton (in image above). The electromagnetic forces are a minor component in the behavior of quarks within the bag of hadrons. The strong force is two orders of magnitude larger than the electromagnetic one and in addition the gluon, carrier of the force, can self interact, in contrast to the photon. That is why the "image of a proton" is so complex.

Nevertheless, a quark quantum theory called [lattice  QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics#Lattice_QCD) [can calculate](http://inspirehep.net/record/1094571/plots?ln=en) the masses of hadrons given their specific [valence quark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model) constituents. It is fairly successful as seen in the linked plots. It is an open field of research.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but your answer leads to another question, What are quarks made of? I read the link on Q.C.D. and it seems quarks are the end of the road currently as far as our understanding goes. Are there any ideas or efforts underway to describe them exactly in a mathematical way? They seem very illdefined at the moment.

Comment: IMO a version of string theory comes next, where there is a generic string and all  elementary particles and excitations/ vibrations on the generic string. S0 quarks will just be specific vibrations on a string. There are other proposals,  like preons  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preon . It is not easy to see how such a theory would embed the standard model, but who knows?  Only future experiments will decide.